# Error while performing simple SQL query in Visual studio c++

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++

I've just recently managed to set up a connection to my SQL Server from a Visual studio c++ application, but can't for the life of me make my statements work as they should.

I've got some experience creating medium-large scripts in SQL Server, but for somer reason the below code is simply giving me errors instead of letting me fetch the data and work through it.

As I mentioned I have no issues with the connection, as I'm not catching any errors when checking the state of the connection.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
using namespace std;

void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle)
{
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        cout << "Message: " << message << "\nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
}

int main() {

    SQLHENV env;
    SQLHDBC dbc;
    SQLHSTMT stmt;
    SQLRETURN ret;
    SQLSMALLINT columns;
    int row = 0;

    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
    /* We want ODBC 3 support */
    SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);

    /* Connect to the DSN */
    SQLDriverConnectW(dbc, NULL, L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-L5OT4OH\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Easier;UID=geo;PWD=password123;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

    /* Check for success */
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect";
    }
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(stmt, (SQLWCHAR*)" USE Easier select personid from dbo.TPERSON", SQL_NTS)) {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
    }
    else {
        int id;
        while (SQLFetch(stmt) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            SQLGetData(stmt, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
            cout << id << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As I understand it my code

- Sets up a connection to my local SQL Server DB through ODBC(?)
- Checks said connection
- Attempts to create and execute a very rudimentary SQL Query (that DOES work in my SQL Manager, before anyone asks).
- Iterates through the fetched data to parse and send data to cout.

Could you guys please have a look and see what kind of mistakes I might have made?

I wouldn't have asked such a simple question if there were any comprehensible guides on how to set up SQL server with a C++ application, but I have been completely unable to find one.

**EDIT:**

show_error gives the following error message:

> Message: 0018ED9C
>
> SQLSTATE: 0018F5A4

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Added the error message in the edit

Comment: Use `wcout` in `show_error` in place of `cout`. This way you'd print actual message text, rather than the address at which it's stored (which is not at all helpful).

Comment: `SQLExecDirect` most likely wants a wide string (the fact that you had to cast to `SQLWCHAR*` to get it to compile should have been a red flag). Make it `L" USE Easier..."`, same way you did in `SQLDriverConnectW`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the advice, man. Seems like SQLExecDirect didn't like the fact that I had included "Use Easier" - as it was already explicitly stated in the Connect. 
I'm not really sure how to mark a comment as an answer, but I'd definately give you some +rep if I knew how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the SQLExecDirect didn't like the fact that I explicitly it to use "USE Easier" as it's already declared in the connection string.